# Cancel http request in angular 2+

Tags: angular, interceptor, loader

I want to cancel running request by clicking button

When http request call then loader is running but most of the time request taking longer time so that I want to cancel that request while running

here is my html code

```
<div *ngIf="progress.state | async; let state">
    <div class="loading-icon" *ngIf="state.active">
        <button class="btn btn--primary" (click)="cancelRequest()">Cancle Request</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my loader.ts file

```
import { HttpModule, BrowserXhr } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgProgressModule, NgProgressBrowserXhr } from 'ngx-progressbar';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './spinner.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgProgressModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    SpinnerComponent
  ],
  providers: [
      { provide: BrowserXhr, useClass: NgProgressBrowserXhr },
  ],
  exports:[
    SpinnerComponent
  ]
})
export class PageloaderModule {
  cancelRequest(){

  }
 }
```

I'm trying to set a Boolean variable in http interceptor but not working

So how can I cancel running http request

Comment: I don't see a HTTP request in your code. What about storing the subscription returned from the `http.get()`, `http.post()`, ... call and call `unsubscribe()` when you don't want to wait for a response anymore?

Comment: I want to cancel request  when the loader is running and loader is run when the http request is call any ware from the project

Comment: You need to either unsubscribe or throw an error (possibly RxJS TimeoutError) at some point. You're using Http and not HttpClient. There are no interceptors in Http.

Comment: As for HttpClient, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938931/angular-httpclient-default-and-specific-request-timeout . I guess that instead of `.timeout(timeoutObservable)` you will need `.merge(cancelSubject)` and then you can do `cancelSubject.error(new TimeoutError)` anywhere.