# Backend returned code 0, body was: [object ProgressEvent] - Angular 5

Tags: angular, .net-core, timeout

In my `angular application`, I'm calling an API that takes **more than 2 minutes** to respond but after 2 minutes, angular throws following error;

> Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> Backend returned code 0, body was: [object ProgressEvent]
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

I've tried every possible solution that I found on internet and SO like;

1. Adding timeout on service call;

   `return this.httpClient.post<ViewModelResponse>(this.baseUrl + this._getMetaDataUrl, { headers: this.configurations.getHeaderWithAuth() }).timeout(300000);`
2. Adding timeout with pipe

   `return this.httpClient.post<ViewModelResponse>(this.baseUrl + this._getMetaDataUrl, { headers: this.configurations.getHeaderWithAuth() }).pipe(timeout(300000));`
3. Implements HttpInterceptor [followed this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986060/2660342)
4. Added timeout in headers `"timeout": ${300000}`
5. Increased IIS server timeout to 20 minutes..
6. People also suggested changes in Proxy file but I don't have any proxy file..

**But nothing worked for me**.. all these solutions failed once the API response exceeds 2 minutes. I'm using `dotnet core` at backend and it returns proper response everytime.

> In case of Pipe(timeout()), call was at backend but angular throws
> error that response is null

**Any kind of help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I finally found my issue. And as everyone was saying, it was a **backend server (Dotnet Core)** Issue.

> Setting the RequestTimeout="00:20:00" on the aspNetCore tag in web.config and deploying the site resolved my problem.

[This article has details of adding timeout in dotnet core application.](https://medium.com/aspnetcore/increase-the-timeout-of-asp-net-core-application-9a7b4f6deebf)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago.
The problem is definitelly the back end.
You have to add a directive in your `ConfigureServices`, inside your `Startup` class.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is the Microsoft's documentation I followed to fix the error. If using the exact url does not work, you should use allorigin policy like this:
`builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();`