# How do increase angular request timeout

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a request take about 2-5 minutes but it always break at 30s
Is there any way to increase request timeout or prevent request was canceled automatically with angular 8.x?

Comment: You need to configure the timeout from the server-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default and specific request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938931/default-and-specific-request-timeout)

Comment: Hi @SurenSrapyan, I see that my problem came from client side, my browser cancel request after 30s.

Comment: @Avdhoota, no, i tried it before, it couldn't help me increase the timeout

Comment: my issue came from server-side, we using cloudfront and it was limited at 30s

Comment: Finally, I found that the timeout was controlled by the server instead of the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the timeout operator. Since rxjs 5.5.2 you need to use the pipe method with lettable operators. And assuming you are using the HttpClient to make your requests, there is no need for a map(response => response.json()).

Like this:

import { timeout, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

http.get('https://example.com')
   .pipe(
      timeout(2000),
      catchError(e => {
        // do something on a timeout
        return of(null);
      })
    )

Comment: do this way only decrease the timeout limit . it can't help me to increase timeout