# How to handle long running http requests between Angular and backend API CORE

Tags: c#, .net, angular, .net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I am getting timeout issue if my http request is taking long time.  The connection of angular and api core is broken, but the api core is running background.
So How can I handle the http request time. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, [default timeout handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938931/default-and-specific-request-timeout/45941133#45941133) can help you. If you assume that your http requests can last so long, provide appropriate value, but please keep in mind that it's bad pattern.