# Request timeout for HttpClient

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, asp.net-core, httpclient

I am working in TypeScript with ASP.NET Core [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release).

**Scenario:**

I am working with a large data response service on the backend side. That took more than two minutes to load the data. As I know the default timeout for `HttpClient` is for two minutes for `localhost`
`(Chrome hold for request time out)`, but when I publish my code to the IIS site, after two minutes it gives a `500 Internal Server Error`.

**On the API side:**

I have set the time to 1000 seconds.

```
 services.AddDbContext<BusinessContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"], opts => opts.CommandTimeout(1000).EnableRetryOnFailure()));
```

**On the web side:**

**Try 1:**

This is a simple service call

```
async getData(lookUp: Lookup): Promise<PacketSearchItem[]> {
    return await this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + "Packet/ManualSearch", lookUp)
      .toPromise() as PacketSearchItem[];
}
```

**Try: 2**

```
async getData(lookUp: Lookup): Promise<PacketSearchItem[]> {
    return await this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + "Packet/ManualSearch", lookUp).pipe(timeout(10000000))
      .toPromise() as PacketSearchItem[];
}
```

**Try: 3**

```
async getData(lookUp: Lookup): Promise<PacketSearchItem[]> {
    return await this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + "Packet/ManualSearch", lookUp, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ timeout: `${10000000}` })}).pipe(timeout(10000000))
      .toPromise() as PacketSearchItem[];
}
```

**Research on Google:**

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938931/default-and-specific-request-timeout)

I used the upper link code to, but it gives me the same error, because after 2 minutes a request time out occur in Google Chrome.

**Error Screenshot:**

**1) Console Error:**

[image]

**2.) Network Error:**

[image]

I want to wait for Chrome to get the response from the API.

I already added the **CORS policy**:

```
 services.AddCors(options => {
     options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
         builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader()
         .AllowCredentials());
});

app.UseExceptionHandler(
    builder => {
        builder.Run(
            async context => {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (error != null) {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Application-Error", error.Error.Message);
                    // CORS
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-expose-headers", "Application-Error");

                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I found the answer. It is problem in a ASP.NET Core configuration file:

**web.config**

```
 <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00">
```

We have to increase the time-out here.

**Helping link:**

[Reference](https://medium.com/dotnet-hub/increase-the-timeout-of-asp-net-core-application-9a7b4f6deebf#:%7E:text=config%20to%20your%20project%20and,cause%20it%20not%20to%20timeout.)

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, this is not a timeout issue, but a [cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (CORS) issue.

You should probably take some time to learn about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and how to [enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors).

Comment: No it's not CORS Problem I already Define it in my api see the update question. My whole project is working fine the problem is in when the response time is more than 2 mintues.